# Jenkins - connection to slave lost - ClosedChannelException

Tags: jenkins, jnlp, windows-server-2012-r2

Every now and then all the Jenkins jobs that are currently running on some of my Jenkins slaves fail for the following reason:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$OnReady.run(IOHub.java:721)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Issue happens only on some slaves, so it's not a problem with the master, I think...

In Jenkins slave log I got this one:

```
JNLP agent connected from xxxx
Slave.jar version: 3.7
This is a Windows agent
just before slave SLAVE01 gets online ...
executing prepare script ...
setting up slave SLAVE01 ...
slave setup done.
Agent successfully connected and online
ERROR: Connection terminated
[8mha:////4JmhQISHGLISGlsTHOZXEPbCK6pxtJiroBix+jLdfCfh/YKcSsnpDAAAAVx+LCAAAAAAAA98nsLuhNKKmjNKU4P08vOT+vODjuha&SHllHSE4tKMnMz/PLL0mV3NWzufebKBsTA0NFEYMUmgZnCA1SyAABjKpSSsdxNaiYAAAAA==[0mjava.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$OnReady.run(IOHub.java:721)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In slave's windows event log I got the following records:

```
SLAVE01 7031    Error   Microsoft-Windows-Service Control Manager   System      27-03-2018 06:32:05 The Jenkins agent (jenkinsslave-c__jenkins) service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 0 milliseconds: Restart the service.
SLAVE01 0       Warning jenkinsslave-c__jenkins                     Application 27-03-2018 06:32:05 Child process [596 - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe -Xrs  -jar "c:\jenkins\slave.jar" -jnlpUrl http://master:1234/computer/SLAVE01/slave-agent.jnlp -secret 8b64b1c4c643a36587dfaa4bf106b9099ad1c5cd8f12333a4f2fa518363aa250] finished with -1
SLAVE01 0       Warning jenkinsslave-c__jenkins                     Application 27-03-2018 06:31:53 SIGINT to 3552 failed - Killing as fallback
SLAVE01 0       Warning jenkinsslave-c__jenkins                     Application 27-03-2018 06:31:52 SIGINT to 2308 failed - Killing as fallback
```

Any ideas what is going on?